# Is it possible to bind to the Click event and not use an anonymous function -- I just want to call a named function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code. The first attempt at binding to click event does not work. The second way does. The first shows the alert "CheckBox1" during Page_Load. The second one shows the alert "CheckBox4" during the proper time -- during clicks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document.getElementById(checkBox1ID)).click( SetCheckBox1State(this.checked) );
    $(document.getElementById(checkBox4ID)).click(function () { SetCheckBox4State(this.checked) });
});

    function SetCheckBox1State(checked) {
    alert("CheckBox2");
    var radNumericTextBox1 = $find(radNumericTextBox1ID);
    var wrapperElement = $get(radNumericTextBox1._wrapperElementID);
    var label = $(wrapperElemenet.getElementsByTagName("label")[0]);

    if (checked) {
        radNumericTextBox1.enable();
        label.addClass("LabelEnabled");
        label.removeClass("LabelDisabled");
    }
    else {
        radNumericTextBox1.disable();
        label.addClass("LabelDisabled");
        label.removeClass("LabelEnabled");
    }
}

function SetCheckBox4State(checked) {
    alert("CheckBox4");
    var radNumericTextBox2 = $find(radNumericTextBox2ID);
    var wrapperElement = $get(radNumericTextBox2._wrapperElementID);
    var label = $(wrapperElemenet.getElementsByTagName("label")[0]);

    if (checked) {
        radNumericTextBox2.enable();
        label.addClass("LabelEnabled");
        label.removeClass("LabelDisabled");
    }
    else {
        radNumericTextBox2.disable();
        label.addClass("LabelDisabled");
        label.removeClass("LabelEnabled");
    }
}
```

Am I doing something improper? I'd rather not use an anonymous function...but maybe this just how things work?

Comment: you could use $("#"+checkBoxID) instead of $(document.getElementById(checkBox1ID))

Comment: Thanks for the improvement. :)

Comment: where are you getting checkBox1ID from, is it actual id of the checkbox? if so, you would need to put them in quotes. And same for all other IDs

Comment: The ID is declared on the main ASPX page. The CheckBoxs are an exceptional case -- I am working with a lot of ASP.NET controls. These controls have to be found on the main page and their client ID written down because the client ID can't be retrieved from a separate javascript file. It's really lame. To be clear.. it's more likely a limitation on Telerik controls, not the ASP.NET controls themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
 .click( SetCheckBox1State(this.checked) );
```

Assigns the `.click()` function to be the *output* of this function: `SetCheckBox1State(this.checked)`.

You will have to get rid of the argument (make it internal) and just pass the function name:

```
.click( SetCheckBox1State );
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this more OO? As in, if I wanted to make a generic SetCheckBoxState -- how would I go about inferring which checkbox had called the method if I am unable to pass parameters?

Comment: @SeanAnderson: A common pattern is to use a closure: `function SetCheckBox1State(checked){ return function(event){ … }; }`. The returned function will have access to the `checked` variable. EDIT: the `.click()` call would then look like what you have in the original code.

Comment: I would like to call SetCheckBox1State multiple times, though. It should be called on initial load, as well as whenever the CheckBox becomes checked. Just seems weird that I can't have both?